# Calculate md5 from werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, but saving the object as file is empty

Tags: python, flask, md5

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #get pdf file
        pdffile = form.pdfupload.data
        #next line causes exception
        filemd5 = hashlib.md5()
        filemd5.update(pdffile.read())
        filemd5name = filemd5.hexdigest()
        #next save file
        pdffile.save(filemd5name+'.pdf')
```

Unfortunatelly, after hashlib.md5 the filemd5name+'.pdf' is an empty.

Is there any way to get md5 from the file and saving the whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've performed a `read` on the file stream, you need to `seek` back to the start of the file to save it successfully.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #get pdf file
        pdffile = form.pdfupload.data
        #next line causes exception
        filemd5 = hashlib.md5()
        filemd5.update(pdffile.read())
        filemd5name = filemd5.hexdigest()
        #next save file
        pdffile.seek(0)
        pdffile.save(filemd5name+'.pdf')
```